# print prime nos upto 100 in javascript

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    var i, j, k = 1;
    for (i = 3; i < 100; i++) {
      for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
          k = 0;
          break
        }
      }
    }
    if (k == 1) {
      alert(i);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to print prime nos in js from 2 to 100.However the code is not producing the desired result.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the reason for downvote?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: @KevinB i do not mean that

Comment: I think if you step through this code you'll get a lot of insight as to what is going wrong.  There's too much wrong here to fix with a one line change.  Go through it with a debugger, and you'll quickly see where things start to go awry.

Comment: whats wrong in the code

Comment: try using meaningful variable names such as "divisor". They may help you see the issue

Comment: `[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]`… TA-DAAAA!

Answer (score 0):

First you only need to check till `j <= (i/2)` in your for loop.
also your `if(k==1)` need to be inside the outer `for` loop

```js
    var i, j;
    for (i = 3; i < 100; i++) {
        var k = 1;
        for (j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                prime = false;
                k = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (k == 1) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `document.write` is evil. Please don't advise others to use it. It has very limited use cases. Use `console.log()` for testing.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I just wanted to print the result on screen so when running the code can easily see the output

Comment: How is `console.log(...)` simpler than `document.write()`? I don't think so. Also, since SO is about informing others, using bad practices in the answers for simplicity sake isn't really doing anyone a favor.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Changed it to `console.log()`